# Kafka streams deletes data from topic it produces to?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a simple Kafka streams app written in Java Spring Boot (spring-cloud-stream binder for Kafka etc.) The app reads from a source topic with 120 Million records and does an aggregation of same keyed messages by joining them as a string and pushes to a temp topic say as a single string.
Idea is I want to use these same keyed messages in another downstream app as a lookup data(I would lose everything but latest if I just used a globalKTable as is on the source topic).

This is the code for this aggregation:

```
public void process(@Input("source_input_channel") KStream<String, SOURCETOPICSCHEMA> sourceTopicKStream
    ) {


        sourceTopicKStream
                .selectKey(((key, value) -> String.valueOf(value.getPrwhrrn())))
                .groupByKey()
                .aggregate(() -> initStr,
                        (key, value, agg) -> {

                            return agg + "::" + value.getSequence() + "|" + value.getName()+"|"+value.getCae()+"|"+value.getSoc()+
                            "|"+value.getSocM()+"|"+value.getCdCat()+"|"+value.prrn()+"|"+value.getContract()+"|"+
                        value.getPerP()+"|"+value.getPerM()+"|"+value.getPer()+"|"+value.getCdTer()+"|"+value.getCdSyn()+"|"+value.getCdCont();
                        },
                        Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
                .toStream()
                .peek(((key, value) -> log.info("key: {} VALUE: {} ", key,value)))
                .to("GROUPED_AGG_TOPIC");


    }
```

My problem is after  this aggregation logic starts pushing data to GROUPED_AGG_TOPIC, and the consumer lag for this aggregation app is also going down to 0 on the source topic. But I see that messages count in the GROUPED_AGG_TOPIC starts reducing all the way down to 0 if I let this aggregation app keep running. Sometimes even before it's consumed all 120 million  messages from source topic I see that the count on GROUPED_AGG_TOPIC keeps reducing from it's highest count.

I can't understand what's deleting messages from the GROUPED_AGG_TOPIC that's already being produced. `retention.ms` also is set to -1 for this topic so messages never expire and get removed by Kafka.
Another thing I have noted is the internal changelog topic for the aggregation app like this one:
`app-app-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000002-changelog`
has all the messages in it and never get removed like on the output topic GROUPED_AGG_TOPIC